# How to improve math/statistics education at the university

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am currently studying mathematics at the university and I feel like there is certainly a lot of room for improvement. I am interested how you guys think the mathematical education at the university might be improved?

I sometimes think that  maybe the Professors should focus more on explaining the underlying ideas in the lecture, than work through almost every single proof, as quite often they do not really contain any new ideas (if they do however the proof is very much welcome). Especially in Stochastics, and Statistics I think that it might be more important to provide an intuition for the math than proof a lot of theorems, which the students cant really appreciate. Also when I compare e.g. they way Youtube Channels like 3Blue1Brown can convey complicated ideas in a way such that everybody can understand it, I wonder whether the way lectures are held at the university should be replaced by something more useful.

Comment: you don't think proofs help with understanding the underlying ideas?

Comment: sometimes they do, sometimes they dont. I just think sometimes it might be more beneficial to explain the idea of the theorem in the lecture and let the students work through the proof themselves at home.

Comment: There is a separate forum about mathematical education, if you can think of a less subjective question then you could better place it there.  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Currently your question is subjective on multiple levels (this multiplicity makes it especially problematic). Besides the possible differences in opinions about the best type of math education, there are also different viewpoints against which these opinions are discussed. The universities that you speak about may be different from the universities that I have in mind. Then we might agree in principle but still end in an apparent argument because we don't speak about the same (this happens in many discussions, people actually agreeing but stating it differently or having different viewpoints).

Answer (score 1):

Say a professor/instructor is introducing a new concept to his class. He or she probably has a tentative outline for how the day will/should go:

1. introduce a super easy example before to motivate the idea, using the idea that hasn't been explained yet,
2. before the proof, tell how it will be completed (preferably using very few sentences),
3. do proof, justifying every line with tools that have been used before,
4. after proof, reiterate how everything "went" (basically do step 2 again),
5. do another example, using the concept again
6. assign homework problems having them re-prove it, and use the idea.

Most instructors get pretty close to something like this. If they can't or don't, it might be for circumstantial reasons, which makes me suspect that t would be difficult to legislate some rule(s) that would improve every university's instructors' performance.

For the average student, I think the primary enemy is frustration. Frustration can be useful when it drives a student to work more on a problem; however, it can also push a student away from his/her work. For that reason, I am pretty optimistic on the capacity for educational technology, as well as extracurricular programs. I think the capacity for the number of students to learn statistics "well" can be increased quite a bit if parts of the classroom experience are gamified, if the perceived stakes are lowered, and they spend leisure time working on problems (for example: a summer program that teaches techniques to analyze data and provides students with internships).

It seems that often times there will be one or two students that do very well in a statistics class, but these students will also be the ones that are self-driven and prefer to do their assignments by themselves. Explaining this "optimal" behavior is unnecessary, and it probably isn't effective to try to have the other students replicate it. Rather, extra resources that are "fun" should be provided to the others.

Comment: Are these technologies already employed at universities?

Comment: Further I think it is also very important for the students to see what the mathematical statistics can actually do if applied. Our stochastics course is so extremely theoretical and measurement based that it is impossible for those who did not participate in a more applied statistic course yet, to see how cool stats actually is.

Comment: @SebastianFischer I'm sure they've started, but there's more to do. Yeah, good point. But how much of that falls on the instructor and isn't built into steps 1-6?

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your problem is that you like math and you seem to have an intuitive bent.  Both of these are getting in the way of you understanding why the professor does what the professor does.

First, a lot of people in math courses, even upper division math courses, are not math or statistics majors and they may very well hate math.  They are in the audience too.

Second, sixty-five percent of the population are concrete, step-by-step thinkers.  They will struggle if you explain the implications before doing the proof.  Indeed, they may not value the implications as the person providing them could be over-valuing or under-valuing their true, long-run importance to *that* person.

Because the instructor is teaching to both groups, but your group is a definite minority, the instruction satisfies nobody.  There are definitely students out there who wish the professor would spend more time with the proofs and solving things as algorithms and skip the "meaning."  How can anyone determine the meaning or importance of anything for anyone other than themselves?

Now let me tell you how I would alter math education from K-undergraduate.  I would ban $y=7x^2+2x-16$.  Everything would be a word problem from beginning to end because no user of math (I am purposefully ignoring the makers of math) will ever be asked by a customer to turn to page 83 and solve problem 5.  Instead, they will provide a very messy account of the problem they are facing.  The solution of that problem may very well be $y=7x^2+2x-16$ but the breakdown in math when you are outside the academic field of math is converting language into flexible problem solutions.

I mean that more than simply deciding that a solution should algorithmically follow from the word problem.  In many cases, algebraic solutions, trigonometric solutions, and geometric solutions are available to solve a problem.  The problem's specification shouldn't lead you to form unless you want to narrow the thinking.

To think about this in statistics, if there are three different solutions in Frequentist, Bayesian or Fisherian statistics, then which one follows from the question and why?  Could it be more than one?  Why?